# Rails app works fine on local machine but 500 error occurs on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my rails app on Heroku and it worked fine. I had a 'name' column in the users table. Then, in local machine, I renamed 'name' column into 'username'. It still worked fine on my machine.

Previously, The code in my view file was :-

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

Then, I changed it to :-

```
<%= @user.username %>
```

Again, I pushed the changes to heroku but the app encountered 500 error. When I ran heroku logs, I got the following error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username' for #<User:0x007fac4558c1b0>)
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:-**

The code in user model is:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #some codes
 #..........
    validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, 
      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
#.......
#some codes
end
```

Comment: did you refresh the database on the heroku side? What is the model expecting?

Comment: No.How to do that?

Comment: did you make a change to the schema as a rake migration or in a different way? You either need to run the same migration on heroku or push the new db.

Comment: I generated migration file and renamed the column. Then, I ran Heroku run rake db:migrate after pushing to heroku. Now, what should I do? Please, help.

Comment: I have changed the model accordingly too.

Comment: So you should be able to see your changes on the heroku platform. Try looking directly at the models in the heroku console. @JohnBeynon suggests this below. Run `heroku run console` and look for your model and new attrs.

Comment: Thanks! Will try next time. Unfortunately, I already ran heroku run rake 
 db:schema:load in production database. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure you updated the column name, try doing a heroku restart to restart the server. I've noticed this is required sometimes even though it shouldn't be.

If that doesn't work, can you paste in your table model here?

Comment: No, Heroku restart didn't work either. I included user model in my edit. Please, help!

Comment: `heroku run console` - and from there look at `User.first` and see if you see a `username` attribute on the user.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try next time. Unfortunately, I already destroyed the production database. :(